# Intel RST crashing! IAStorUI unstable in win 8.1

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, cache, windows-8.1, intel-rst

I have a Z87E-ITX Asrock mobo. Using a new 64G Corsair SSD as cache and a new Western Digi Black Scorpion 750G 2.5" drive. Using windows 8.1. Latest software or not, I can't open Intel RST software without it saying IAStorUI has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly blah blah.

I have had some issues recently with Robotic sounds causing fps drops etc but found it was the HDD. After a standard windows scan and fix (& update to win 8.1) I haven't been able to open Intel RST.

I thought maybe I should try to look for an SSD cache drive checker but as it doesn't show up as a drive, I'm unsure how any program can scan it.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced something similar. I have a Dell Latitude E6530 that was running Win8 without issues. Now with the update to Win8.1, I occasionally experience this crash error:

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL(iaStorA.sys). The Intel RST driver I used is supplied by Dell and is version 12.8.2.1000. Strangely, this version is newer than the version on the Intel website:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Software+Products&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%c2%ae+Rapid+Storage+Technology+(Intel%c2%ae+RST)

I downgraded the driver to the one from the Intel website and so far I haven't experienced the crash. I am not sure if the problem is solved but so far its working for me. However some other people also experienced similar issues:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4a76be32-85b6-4004-9887-0cd42cc2f235/intel-rst-drivers-lockup-windows-81?forum=w8itprohardware

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I always make backups, and I found that after .NET Framework 4.5 was installed, it crash.

What I did? I tried uninstalling the .NET Framework 4.5, but it did not work.

I recovered my Windows from *before* this lovely .NET Framework 4.5 auto-updated.

I disabled .NET Framework 4.5 from the list of Windows Updates, and now? I'm happy!!!

(Windows 7 for me)